# Parallax Scrolling with Stellar - Images disappear at top, rather than go off screen

Tags: jquery, parallax

I am hoping you can help. I am currently trying to produce my first parallax scrolling website but have encountered a problem. The scrolling is working great but when the moving images get to the top of the page, they disappear rather than carrying on off the screen. You can see what I am talking about here:

www.rhvc.co.uk

Please look at the cloud (as all of the others go behind a .png).

Any help in getting the cloud to graciously leave the window would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I have worked it out - just in case anyone else has this problem. Each of the elements must have a defined height property, otherwise they just disappear.